# Setting up a secure (wss) websockets server with Apollo and GraphQL

Tags: websocket, graphql, apollo, wss, subscriptions

I am using the following pattern to set up a websockets connection for Apollo/GraphQL subscriptions:

```
import express from 'express';
import {
  graphqlExpress,
  graphiqlExpress,
} from 'apollo-server-express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import { execute, subscribe } from 'graphql';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { SubscriptionServer } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws';

import { schema } from './src/schema';

const PORT = 3000;
const server = express();

server.use('*', cors({ origin: `http://localhost:${PORT}` }));

server.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({
  schema
}));

server.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
  endpointURL: '/graphql',
  subscriptionsEndpoint: `ws://localhost:${PORT}/subscriptions`
}));

// Wrap the Express server
const ws = createServer(server);
ws.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Apollo Server is now running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  // Set up the WebSocket for handling GraphQL subscriptions
  new SubscriptionServer({
    execute,
    subscribe,
    schema
  }, {
    server: ws,
    path: '/subscriptions',
  });
});
```

How can I change the connection to use the secure websockets protocol? Simply changing 'ws://' to 'wss://' does not work.

Comment: There is any way to test its performance with tools such as JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample for `graphql-subscription` websocket secure connection.

Here is link: https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-server-express-starter/tree/master/src/subscription/wss-with-nodejs-server

The key point is you need `tls` or `ssl` credentials.

For development, you can generate self-signed credentials using `openssl`.

Comment: How do you know if wss is already set? from my end, it still can't find wss

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `https` instead of the `http` package.
You also would need to have a certificate. Eather a self-signed or from a certification authority.

It could look like this:

```js
import { createServer } from 'https';

...

// load / get certificate

...

const wss = createServer(sslCredentails, server);
wss.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Apollo Server is now running on https://localhost:${PORT}`);
  // Set up the WebSocket for handling GraphQL subscriptions
  new SubscriptionServer({
    execute,
    subscribe,
    schema
  }, {
    server: wss,
    path: '/subscriptions',
  });
});
```